# Dockerfile for Python App: ChromeDriver and Google Chrome Installation Issue

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am encountering an issue with my Dockerfile. Previously, it was working fine, but now it is throwing an error that reads "cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:53190 This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 110 Current browser version is 109.0.5414.119". I am unsure how to resolve this issue. Here is the code for my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app 

COPY ./requirements.txt .

COPY ./ . 

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

i am not an expert in docker,
i am a python developer,
also above dockerfile is not written by me,
i am clueless what to do